# Replace string in line without adding new line?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to replace string in a line which contain patternB, something like this:

from:

```
some lines
line contain patternA
some lines
line contain patternB
more lines
```

to:

```
some lines
line contain patternA
some lines
line contain patternB xx oo
more lines
```

I have code like this:

```
inputfile = open("d:\myfile.abc", "r")
outputfile = open("d:\myfile_renew.abc", "w")
obj = "yaya"
dummy = ""
item = []

for line in inputfile:
    dummy += line
    if line.find("patternA") != -1:
        for line in inputfile:
            dummy += line
            if line.find("patternB") != -1:
                item = line.split()
                dummy += item[0] + " xx " + item[-1] + "\n"
                break
outputfile.write(dummy)
```

It do not replace the line contain "patternB" as expected, but add an new line below it like :

```
some lines
line contain patternA
some lines
line contain patternB
line contain patternB xx oo
more lines
```

What can I do with my code?

Comment: Fix the indentation please. i would do it, but it might affect the logic of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is, since you append line to dummy in the beginning of the for loop and then the modified version again in the "if" statement. Also why check for Pattern A if you treat is as you treat everything else?

```
inputfile = open("d:\myfile.abc", "r")
outputfile = open("d:\myfile_renew.abc", "w")
obj = "yaya"
dummy = ""
item = []

for line in inputfile:
    if line.find("patternB") != -1:
        item = line.split()
        dummy += item[0] + " xx " + item[-1] + "\n"
    else:
        dummy += line
outputfile.write(dummy)
```

Comment: Check patternA is necessary in my actual situation since there are many patternB in my file

Comment: this does not make sense. ☺

Comment: and the "else" part contains all other patterns; all except B. Pattern A does not have to get special treatment.

Comment: I just found all lines contains patternB in file had been replace, how can I stop the replacement with another pattern

Comment: I am not quite sure i understand. All lines containing Pattern B have been replaced and you want to do what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
s = '''some lines
line contain patternA
some lines
line contain patternB
more lines'''

print(s.replace('patternB', 'patternB xx oo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest will be:
1. Read all File into string
2. Call string.replace
3. Dump string to file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep line by line iterator
(for a big file)

```
for line in inputfile:
    if line.find("patternB") != -1:
        dummy = line.replace('patternB', 'patternB xx oo')
        outputfile.write(dummy)
    else:
        outputfile.write(line)
```

This is slower than other responses, but enables big file processing.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
import os

def replace():

    f1 = open("d:\myfile.abc","r")
    f2 = open("d:\myfile_renew.abc","w")
    ow = raw_input("Enter word you wish to replace:")
    nw = raw_input("Enter new word:")
    for line in f1:
        templ = line.split()
        for i in templ:
            if i==ow:
                f2.write(nw)
            else:
                f2.write(i)
        f2.write('\n')
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    os.remove("d:\myfile.abc")
    os.rename("d:\myfile_renew.abc","d:\myfile.abc")

replace()
```